# Catch the bird on top of the notice board?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

When I walk near the train station there is a notice board. Almost every time, sitting atop it, is a yellow bird that will fly away when I get close. Is there some way to capture this bird??

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, you cannot. The bird is simply there to let you know that there's a new post on the message board that you haven't read yet. This is actually a very common question for every game, and often people will post trolling messages trying to get players to jump through hoops to catch it, but the sad reality is you cannot.

Comment: Drat, I thought I was getting pretty close on hitting it with my net.

Answer (score 9):

No, there isn't. The bird is just there to notify you that there are new notices on the bulletin board. If there are any unread notices the bird will appear, otherwise you won't see it.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot catch the bird because some of the animal crossing new leaf characters will say... "I know a little screat... when you see the yellow bird that means a new post is there that you didnt read" Or something like that.So the answer is NO you cannot catch the bird no matter how hard you try!